# Sort multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

I want sort the following multidimensional array based on date using php.

```
$arr = Array(
[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM',
        [1] => '2015-03-19 11:30 AM',
        [2] => '2015-03-19 03:30 PM',
        [3] => '2015-03-19 07:30 PM',
        [4] => '2015-03-19 09:30 PM'
    ),
  [14] => Array
    (
        [0] => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM',
        [1] => '2015-03-19 04:30 PM',
        [2] => '2015-03-19 09:30 PM',
        [3] => '2015-03-20 07:30 AM',
        [4] => '2015-03-20 04:30 PM',
        [5] => '2015-03-20 09:30 PM'
    )
 );
```

I want the final output/result array like,

```
arr[13][0] => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM'
arr[14][0] => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM'
arr[13][1] => '2015-03-19 11:30 AM',

.. likewise.
```

the keys are important to me (13 and 14 are med ids and 0,1 are schdule ids).

Comment: Looking at your expected outcome, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way arrays work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your expected outcome, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way arrays work. You can't interleave different levels of a multi-dimensional array

Try restructuring your array to a structure that can be used more easily:

```
$arr = array(
    13 => array(
        0 => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM',
        1 => '2015-03-19 11:30 AM',
        2 => '2015-03-19 03:30 PM',
        3 => '2015-03-19 07:30 PM',
        4 => '2015-03-19 09:30 PM'
    ),
   14 => array(
        0 => '2015-03-19 07:30 AM',
        1 => '2015-03-19 04:30 PM',
        2 => '2015-03-19 09:30 PM',
        3 => '2015-03-20 07:30 AM',
        4 => '2015-03-20 04:30 PM',
        5 => '2015-03-20 09:30 PM'
    )
);

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $med_id => $v1) {
    foreach($v1 as $sched_id => $v2) {
        $newArr[] = (object) array(
            'med_id' => $med_id,
            'sched_id' => $sched_id,
            'appointment' => $v2
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can sort it using

```
usort(
    $newArr,
    function($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a->appointment) > strtotime($b->appointment);
    }
);
var_dump($newArr);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/twQlMh)

Answer (score 0):

Great solution by Mark..that was perfect solution...

The alternative solution i used ..converted array's into single dimension using med id and sch id used asort.

```
$arr = array(
'13_0' => strtotime('2015-03-19 07:30 AM'),
'13_1' => strtotime('2015-03-19 11:30 AM'),
'13_2' => strtotime('2015-03-19 03:30 PM'),
'13_3' => strtotime('2015-03-19 07:30 PM'),
'13_4' => strtotime('2015-03-19 09:30 PM'),

'14_0' => strtotime('2015-03-19 07:30 AM'),
'14_1' => strtotime('2015-03-19 04:30 PM'),
'14_2' => strtotime('2015-03-19 09:30 PM'),
'14_3' => strtotime('2015-03-20 07:30 AM'),
'14_4' => strtotime('2015-03-20 04:30 PM'),
'14_5' => strtotime('2015-03-20 09:30 PM')
);
asort($arr);
```